# Error: ORA-04072: invalid trigger type

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I did the following trigger:

```
create or replace trigger check_club_location
before of insert or update on club
for each row 
declare cnt number;
begin
    select count(*) into cnt
    from club
    where club.location = :new.location;

    if (cnt > 0) then
    raise_application_error (-20100, 'Erro: ja existe club nessa localizacao.');
    end if;
end;
/
```

After I tried to run this trigger in Oracle APEX, the following error message appears:

> ORA-04072: invalid trigger type.

I already tried many fixes but none worked on my trigger unfortunatelly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo

```
before of insert or update on club
```

remove the "of", Oracle is complaining that "of" is not a valid trigger type